# Grid Problem Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> I have a 2x2 grid square say, I can fit a shape like this: 
>   [image: ruby]
>   Such that there is one missing square. I can arrange this in any way so that the missing square can be located anywhere. I can do the same for a 4x4 or a 8x8 or a 16x16 square. In fact, I can do this for any square $2^k$ x $2^k$ for integer $k$ (positive). Prove the previous statement by any method.

Supposing it holds for a $2^k$x$2^k$ square. Prove the property for: $4(2^k)\times$ $(2^k)$

I realized that:

$4(2^k)\times(2^k) = (2^k)\times(2^k) + (2^k)\times(2^k) + (2^k)\times(2^k) + (2^k)\times(2^k) $

Meaning if the missing spot was in either of the far corners (different corners) another square of $4$ can be formed, of which, a trimino can fit, hence leaving one blank square.

**(1) Is this an accurate proof by induction?**

**(2) Is there a way to do this using contradiction?**

Comment: The sentence starting "Meaning if..." is not clear, especially what you mean by "another square of $4$ can be formed." Could you clarify? And do you really need to use induction? You could easily do a proof by cases: the orientation in your graph works for all unit squares not on the right or top borders of the large square, and you can use other orientations for those.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence

"Meaning if the missing spot was in either of the far corners (different corners) another square of 4 can be formed, of which, a trimino can fit, hence leaving one blank square."

is not a proof. Note that the missing square can be ANYWHERE.

Here is a **Hint**:

To prove the inductive step $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$ do the following:

Divide the $2^{n+1} \times 2^{n+1}$ square in $4$ squares of size $2^n \times 2^n$.

The missing tile is in one of these four. By $P(n)$ this can be tiled by your "chair" shape.

Now, you can put another chair in such a way that it covers one corner from each of the remaining three $2^n \times 2^n$ squares. Now you can use again $P(n)$.

I suspect that this is what you were trying to describe in the above proposition, but the way it is written it doesn't say this....

Comment: this is what I was trying to say. but if the missing space is in the middle then $4(2^k x 2^k)$ cannot have only one missing spot.

Comment: @Lebes What do you mean in the middle?